# Wanting to change primary monitor on boot

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, bios

So I have this problem. I have a setup with a dual monitor (Samsung, primary) (Asus, secondary). Now, when I boot the pc, the mobo logo and the bios shows up on the secondary one. How can I change it so the bios and all the booting options, show up on the primary?

**Setup specs**

CPU: AMD RYZEN 5 3400g w/ integrated graphics MOBO: asrock b450m-hdv r4.0 RAM 16GB Primary monitor (HDMI) SAMSUNG Secondary monitor (VGA) Asus

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing a software function and a hardware function. The primary monitor is defined in the OS and does not impact the system hardware. You *might* have two options:

First, if your BIOS has an option to define the primary display port you can do that, but not every BIOS offers this.

Second, just plug the monitor you want into the primary port, which probably just means switching the monitors.